# Excel - Key Error Vlookup Question using Python

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to do `vlookup` using `pandas` in python , below is my program but getting `key error = Name error`

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel ('vlookup_pandas.xlsx', Sheet_name = 'Table1',)
df2 = pd.read_excel ('vlookup_pandas.xlsx',Sheet_name = 'Table2')
results = df1.merge(df2, on='Name')
```

Comment: Is there a 'Name' column in your xlsx file?

Comment: The error is telling you that `'Name'` column doesn't exist. What does `print(df1.columns.tolist())` show and likewise for `df2`?

Comment: Yes i have a Name column in both of sheets.

Comment: ['Name ', 'Team'] i get this when  i give Print df1.columns.tolist())

Comment: Looks like a trailing space after “Name “